# Headers for WebSocket client?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I need to connect Deno (as a client) to a WebSocket server that requires custom headers on connection. I can't seem to find any currently supported method to accomplish this since the `WebSocket` API only allows for the `url` and `protocols` parameters.

Is there any known best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: [The spec does not currently allow for this](https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/16). See these GitHub issues for more info: [denoland/deno#7632](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7632) [denoland/deno#9890](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/9890)